# Setting up a firewall to be in front of my devices using public IP

Tags: firewall, bridge, wan

I'm currently using USG FLEX 500 firewall device from Zyxel.
It has 6 unused ports.
I have 7 PCs each with public IP address assigned to it. I would like to set the firewall up in a way that when someone is trying to connect to the PC, the request goes through the firewall first before reaching the public IP address of the PC. (i.e I would like to put the firewall 'in front of' the PCs while maintaining the public IP assigned to it)
When I asked the manufacturer about this, they suggested that I set up a 'WAN bridge'. Where I allocate a public IP to a unused port, connect the PC to another unused port, then set up a bridge connection between those two ports. But if i set it up this way, I would need 2 ports per device, which means i would run short of ports to set this up for all 7 of my PCs.
Is what i am trying to do possible with the resources I have? , or could there be any other workaround for it ?

Comment: How do you "allocate a public IP to a unused port"? Do you do this on the firewall? If so, that doesn't sound like it would make sense when _bridging_. Or is this something you do in the "upstream" device (ISP router or something)?

Comment: The manufacturer said that it can be done on the firewall UI.

Comment: Maybe, but conceptually it only makes sense when the firewall is routing, not when it's bridging... (and in either case, you should not be limited to "one address per interface"...) How do you receive the public IPs, though? Are they all in a single subnet (like a /29), or are they individual (separate /32's)?

Comment: Public IP addressed are all in the same subnet and provided by the same ISP. The current public IP addressed assigned to the firewall hardware is in the same subnet with the public IP address assigned to other devices that need to be put behind the firewall

Comment: Unclear: By definition a firewall is before the resources it protects. What kind of a setup do you have where the firewall is *behind* the PC? And where is the router? Adding a graphical schema to your post could help.